# BeautifulSoup : Searching on class tags with white spaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to search only for the class name table_body.

for example
These are the methods I tried.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '''
<tr class="table_body notice inside ">1</tr>
<tr class="table_body notice inside ">2</tr>
<tr class="table_body">3</tr>
<tr class="table_body">4</tr>
'''
soup = soup(html, 'lxml')
res1 = soup.find_all('tr', class_='table_body')
res2 = soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda s: s.endswith('table_body'))
res3 = soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda s: s!='table_body notice inside ')

print(res1)
>>> [<tr class="table_body notice inside ">1</tr>, <tr class="table_body notice inside ">2</tr>, <tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
print(res2)
>>> [<tr class="table_body notice inside ">1</tr>, <tr class="table_body notice inside ">2</tr>, <tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
print(res3)
>>> [<tr class="table_body notice inside ">1</tr>, <tr class="table_body notice inside ">2</tr>, <tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
```

Can I search only for tags whose class name is table_body?

Is there a good way?

The reulst that I want.

```python
[<tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
```

Comment: probably `find_all` split string `class` to list of classes and then check every class separatelly.

Answer (score 1):

Using css selectors, the output is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '''
<tr class="table_body notice inside ">1</tr>
<tr class="table_body notice inside ">2</tr>
<tr class="table_body">3</tr>
<tr class="table_body">4</tr>
'''
soup = soup(html, 'lxml')
res1 = soup.find_all('tr', class_='table_body')
res2 = soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda s: s.endswith('table_body'))
res3 = soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda s: s!='table_body notice inside ')

res1 = soup.select('tr[class="table_body"]')
print(res1)
```

Output:

```
[<tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res4 = [t for t in res1 if t['class']==['table_body']]
print(res4)
```

Comment: I don't want to use for and if.
Is there a good way?

Answer (score 0):

#### Css Selectors

Simplest way to get your goal while using `beautifulsoup`, select with a strict condition by `attribute selector`:

```
soup.select("tr[class='table_body']")
```

This will select all `<tr>` with exact this one `class`.

#### Output

```
[<tr class="table_body">3</tr>, <tr class="table_body">4</tr>]
```